# How to pick set of 5 random values from property file using Java?

Tags: java, selenium, random, selenium-webdriver

I have a Property file called `test.properties` in `C:\Test\` Directory.

In the Property file i have *property ID* and *Property* values as follows:

```
TestID=Test1,Test2,Test3,Tes4 upto 10
```

By using Java code how can i pick any 5 random values from the property file and then need to verify the those values are available in the **FE**.

I'm beginner of ***Java*** please help me with some sample code

The code which i have tried as follows:

```
@Test()
public void test() throws Exception{

Properties APPTEXT = new Properties();
Log.info("Getting Input from the Property file");
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("C:\\FilterSection\\dropdown.properties");
APPTEXT.load(fs);
System.out.println ("" +APPTEXT);
Log.info("1. Verifying the Test drop down values are matching in both property file and UI");
String[] expectedDropDownItemsInArray = APPTEXT.getProperty("TestId").trim().split(",");
Random r = new Random();
//System.out.println(expectedDropDownItemsInArray.length);

 ArrayList<String> expectedDropDownItems = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i<expectedDropDownItemsInArray.length; i++)
    expectedDropDownItems.add(expectedDropDownItemsInArray[i]);

System.out.println(expectedDropDownItems+"" );


Thread.sleep(6000);
```

Comment: Any Body can give me the related sample code so that i can understand easily.

Answer (score 3):

You read the values and store them in a `List<String>`. Then you shuffle the list using

```
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

Then you take the 5 first elements from the list.

Comment: What is there to elaborate? How about you trying to implement what I suggest?

Comment: Why need to shuffle? The solution which i want 1st it need to directly pick any five values from the property file then it need to store and check in UI or directly it need to check in the UI

Answer (score 0):

USE RANDOM FUNCTION 
Random rand = new Random();

int idx = rand.nextInt(Array.length);
String random = (Array[idx]);

Comment: could you give me how to pick some random values with sample code